How to fix these weird lines going throughout my mesh and texture?
How to fix these weird lines going throughout my mesh and texture?

I believe its because of the UV mapping but im not sure how to fix it, I tried recalculating normals, unsubdividing, checking my modifiers, tried a antiseam addon but that didnt work.


hello, what weird line? Maybe share your file (only the necessary)?

"I'Ve tried almost everything" Could you give some examples of things you tried?

@moonboots How do I share it?

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think the issue is due to the UV mapping but I dont know how to fix it

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ if the file is too heavy use a platform like workupload and share the link

@moonboots I added the file, the texture probably wont be there but if you add a texture onto it then you'll be able to see the lines.

Check the UV Editor, you'll see that the unwrap is not correct, the faces along the seam are not contiguous in the UV Editor

@moonboots You're right, do you know any ways to fix it?

You need to unwrap again, you can do it with the Project from View option, etc, it really depends on what you want

@moonboots Okay thank you so much for the help

Check the UV Editor, you'll see that the unwrap is not correct, the faces along the seam are not contiguous in the UV Editor. You need to unwrap again, you can do it with the Project from View option, etc, it really depends on what you want.
